# User profile property show in edit details page but in read only mode

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-property

For example I have a user profile property `Department`. I would like to show this property in Edit Profile Page, but as a label and not as an editable Text.

> Not Like this

[image]

> But Like this

[image]

Are there any suggestions on it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking how to make the Users Preferred Name editable in the User Profile?

Comment: I have got some user profile properties. For example Department. I would like to show this in the Edit Profile Page, but just as a label not as a editable textbox. I will update question with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the properties of the field so it is not editable by the user. Check "Do not allow users to edit values for this property".

Comment: You mean properties available in Central Administration site.?

Comment: Yes, through the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: I chose "Do not allow users to edit values for this property" radio button from Edit settings, and it did the job. If you can update your answer with this property name, it will be a good share.. :) Thanks